# How to group a Data list inside a another list using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of data(Element), and it contains another list inside it(SourceElement). And i want to get all the linkid properties without repeating them. How can i do this?

```
public class Element
{
    public int ElementId { get; set; }
    public List<SourceElement> Source { get; set; }
}

public class SourceElement
{
    public int SourceElementId { get; set; }
    public int LinkId { get; set; }     
}
```

This is how it is now

- Example (Element):

  ElementId = 1 Source = {1, 2},{1, 3},{1, 4},{1, 7}

  ElementId = 2 Source = {2, 2},{2, 3},{2, 4},{2, 8}

Final Output must be like this.

LinkIds = {2,3,4,7,8}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So the question is you want `Distinct` LinkId's from all `List<Element>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a list of `elements`:

```
var linkIds = elements.SelectMany(e => e.Source)
                     .Select(s => s.LinkId)
                     .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany` and get all the `SourceElement` collections, once you getted flattened array `Distinct`  on LinkId

```
var output = string.Join(",", elements.SelectMany(s=>s.Source)
                                      .Select(l=>l.LinkId)
                                      .Distinct()
                        ); 

var formattedoutput = String.Format("LinkIds = {{0}}",  output);
```

**Output**

```
LinkIds = {2,3,4,7,8}
```